# Xdebug vs xhprof

Tags: php, xdebug, xhprof

I was using xdebug to profile the use of multi curl in my php code, and the numbers didn't add up to the total, so I used xhprof instead, which seemed to provide better data. Why is xdebug providing seemingly bad profiling info, and is there a way to work around it? I would prefer to use xdebug's profiler, as there are more tools for it.

Comment: You don't mention how the data is wrong, so I can't help you yet. Please provide more info so I can update my answer on your "wrong numbers" claim too.

Answer (score 6):

Xdebug's profiler works in a slightly different way and thus gives different results. (I also know there is a little bug in aggregating data). I would always suggest to use both Xdebug and XHprof.